# PySpark: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am saving a dataframe to a CSV file in PySpark using below statement:

```
df_all.repartition(1).write.csv("xyz.csv", header=True, mode='overwrite')
```

But i am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 218, in main
func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
File "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 138, in read_udfs
arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
File "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 118, in read_single_udf
f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
File "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 58, in read_command
command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
File "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 170, in _read_with_length
return self.loads(obj)
File "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 559, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

i am using PySpark version 2.3.0

I am getting this error while trying to write to a file.

```
    import json, jsonschema
    from pyspark.sql import functions
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType, FloatType
    from datetime import datetime
    import os

    feb = self.filter_data(self.SRC_DIR + "tl_feb19.csv", 13)
    apr = self.filter_data(self.SRC_DIR + "tl_apr19.csv", 15)

    df_all = feb.union(apr)
    df_all = df_all.dropDuplicates(subset=["PRIMARY_ID"])

    create_emi_amount_udf = udf(create_emi_amount, FloatType())
    df_all = df_all.withColumn("EMI_Amount", create_emi_amount_udf('Sanction_Amount', 'Loan_Type'))

    df_all.write.csv(self.DST_DIR + "merged_amounts.csv", header=True, mode='overwrite')
```

Comment: This is code issue, created by wrong import. You may would like to add your code to the Question.

Comment: Please add more code, at least something about "app"

Comment: @syadav added the code. I dont have anything with name app in my code

Comment: @DuyNguyenHoang added the code

Comment: can you include the imports?

Comment: @ankit Please give me your command to submit spark job. I think something wrong with your command

Comment: If you're experiencing this error on Azure Databricks install the dependencies under Libraries under Your_Cluster_Name in Compute. This will resolve the error

Comment: could you please tell me how you solved this problem ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is very clear, there is not the module 'app'. **Your Python code runs on driver, but you udf runs on executor PVM.** When you call the **udf**, spark serializes the `create_emi_amount` to sent it to the executors.

So, somewhere in your method `create_emi_amount` you use or import the app module.
A solution to your problem is to use the same environment in both driver and executors. In `spark-env.sh` set the save Python virtualenv in `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=...` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON=...`.

Comment: could you please expand yours answer ? I'm newbie with Spark, and I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ggeop! He helped me out. ggeop has explained the problem. But the solution may not be correct if the 'app' is his own package.

My solution is to add the file in sparkcontext:

```py
sc = SparkContext()
sc.addPyFile("app.zip")
```

But you have to zip app package first, and you have to make sure the zipped packaged get app directory.
i.e. if your app is at:/home/workplace/app
then you have to do the zip under workplace, which will zip all directories under workplace including app.

The other way is to send the file in spark-submit, as below:

```
--py-files app.zip
--py-files myapp.py
```